# LINQ to Json data retrieval from polymorphic json

Tags: c#, linq, json.net, linq-to-json

I have a polymorphic json string.  Here's what it looks like:

```
{  
   "?xml":{  
      "@version":"1.0",
      "@encoding":"UTF-8"
   },
   "DataFeed":{  
      "@FeedName":"AdminData",
      "Issuer":[  
         {  
            "name":"Apple",
            "symbol":"AAPL-O",
            "active":"1",
            "securities":{  
               "Security":{  
                  "sedol":"B0XXF09",
                  "coverage":{  
                     "Coverage":{  
                        "analyst":{  
                           "@firstName":"Steve",
                           "@lastName":"Jobs",
                           "@rank":"1"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "symbolMappingList":{  
                     "SecuritySymbol":{  
                        "symbolset":{  
                           "id":"11",
                           "symbol":"ISIN",
                           "name":"ISIN",
                           "rixmlName":"ISIN",
                           "researchDirect":"S&P"
                        },
                        "symbol":"US44919P5XXX"
                     }
                  },
                  "symbolMapping":{  
                     "entry":{  
                        "int":"11",
                        "SecuritySymbol":{  
                           "@reference":"../../../symbolMappingList/SecuritySymbol"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "customFields":{  
                     "customField":[  
                        {  
                           "@name":"ADP",
                           "@type":"Textbox",
                           "values":{  
                              "value":"H0192XX"
                           }
                        },
                        {  
                           "@name":"Top 15",
                           "@type":"Dropdown, multiple choice",
                           "values":null
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         {  
            "name":"Microsoft",
            "symbol":"MSFT-OTC",
            "active":"1",
            "securities":{  
               "Security":{  
                  "sedol":"B8FW54",
                  "coverage":{  
                     "Coverage":{  
                        "analyst":{  
                           "@firstName":"Bill",
                           "@lastName":"Gates",
                           "@rank":"1"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "symbolMappingList":{  
                     "SecuritySymbol":[  
                        {  
                           "symbolset":{  
                              "id":"3",
                              "symbol":"CUSIP",
                              "name":"CUSIP",
                              "rixmlName":"CUSIP",
                              "researchDirect":"S&P"
                           },
                           "symbol":"04316A1XX"
                        },
                        {  
                           "symbolset":{  
                              "id":"11",
                              "symbol":"ISIN",
                              "name":"ISIN",
                              "rixmlName":"ISIN",
                              "researchDirect":"S&P"
                           },
                           "symbol":"US04316A10XX"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "symbolMapping":{  
                     "entry":[  
                        {  
                           "int":"3",
                           "SecuritySymbol":{  
                              "@reference":"../../../symbolMappingList/SecuritySymbol"
                           }
                        },
                        {  
                           "int":"11",
                           "SecuritySymbol":{  
                              "@reference":"../../../symbolMappingList/SecuritySymbol[2]"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "customFields":{  
                     "customField":[  
                        {  
                           "@name":"ADP Security Code",
                           "@type":"Textbox",
                           "values":null
                        },
                        {  
                           "@name":"Top 15",
                           "@type":"Dropdown, multiple choice",
                           "values":null
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Someone once helped me with an extension class so that I can retrieve the ADP codes.  Here's the extension class:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<JToken> DescendantsAndSelf(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<JToken>();
        var container = node as JContainer;
        if (container != null)
            return container.DescendantsAndSelf();
        else
            return new[] { node };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<JObject> ObjectsOrSelf(this JToken root)
    {
        if (root is JObject)
            yield return (JObject)root;
        else if (root is JContainer)
            foreach (var item in ((JContainer)root).Children())
                foreach (var child in item.ObjectsOrSelf())
                    yield return child;
        else
            yield break;
    }
}
```

Based on that, here's my query:

```
var compInfo = from issuer in feed.SelectTokens("DataFeed.Issuer").SelectMany(i => i.ObjectsOrSelf())
           where (string)issuer["active"] == "1"
           let security = issuer.SelectTokens("securities.Security").SelectMany(s => s.ObjectsOrSelf()).FirstOrDefault()
           let securitySymbol = issuer.SelectTokens("securities.Security.symbolMappingList")
            .SelectMany(s => s.ObjectsOrSelf()).FirstOrDefault()
           where security != null
           select new
{
               CompName = (string)issuer["name"],
               SEDOL = ((string)security["sedol"]).StartsWith("0") ? 
                String.Format("'{0}", (string)security["sedol"]) : (string)security["sedol"],
               ADP = security["customFields"]
                .DescendantsAndSelf()
                .OfType<JObject>()
                .Where(o => (string)o["@name"] == "ADP Security Code")
                .Select(o => (string)o.SelectToken("values.value"))
                .FirstOrDefault(),
               ISIN = security["symbolMappingList"]
                .DescendantsAndSelf()
                .OfType<JObject>()
                .Where(o => (string)o["SecuritySymbol.symbolset.name"] == "ISIN")
                .Select(o => (string)o.SelectToken("SecuritySymbol.symbol"))
                .FirstOrDefault()
};
```

I'm able to get the ADP codes.  But how can I get the ISIN codes?  I think I'm pretty close, but I get all nulls.  What do I need to change to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
   ISIN = security["symbolMappingList"]
    .DescendantsAndSelf()
    .OfType<JObject>()
    .Where(o => (string)o.SelectToken("symbolset.name") == "ISIN")
    .Select(o => (string)o.SelectToken("symbol"))
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Some notes:

1. You cannot use [indexers](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Item.htm) to select deeply nested tokens, as you try to do with the expression `o["SecuritySymbol.symbolset.name"]`.  Indexers will only return immediate children.  You need to use [`SelectToken()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) to select grandchildren.
2. The value of the `"SecuritySymbol"` property is sometimes an object:

   ```
                "SecuritySymbol":{  
                   "symbolset":{
   ```

   And sometimes an array:

   ```
                "SecuritySymbol":[  
                   {  
                      "symbolset":{
   ```

   Depending upon the number of items therein.  Because of this polymorphism, you cannot just do `SelectToken("SecuritySymbol.symbolset.name")`.  Instead use `DescendantsAndSelf()` to recursively search the value of `SecuritySymbol` and its descendants (whether embedded in an array or not) for an object with the appropriate `"symbolset.name"` child token.

Here is an updated query that has been slightly optimized to eliminate duplicate calls to `SelectToken` and also to filter on the `"sedol"` name:

```
var filterString = "B0XXF09"; // Null if filtering is not desired

var compInfo = from issuer in feed.SelectTokens("DataFeed.Issuer").SelectMany(i => i.ObjectsOrSelf())
               where (string)issuer["active"] == "1"
               let security = issuer.SelectTokens("securities.Security").SelectMany(s => s.ObjectsOrSelf()).FirstOrDefault()
               where security != null
               let sedol = (string)security["sedol"]
               where (sedol != null && filterString == null || sedol.Contains(filterString))
               select new
               {
                   CompName = (string)issuer["name"],
                   SEDOL = sedol.StartsWith("0") ? String.Format("'{0}", sedol) : sedol,
                   ADP = security["customFields"]
                    .DescendantsAndSelf()
                    .OfType<JObject>()
                    .Where(o => (string)o["@name"] == "ADP Security Code")
                    .Select(o => (string)o.SelectToken("values.value"))
                    .FirstOrDefault(),
                   ISIN = security["symbolMappingList"]
                    .DescendantsAndSelf()
                    .OfType<JObject>()
                    .Where(o => (string)o.SelectToken("symbolset.name") == "ISIN")
                    .Select(o => (string)o.SelectToken("symbol"))
                    .FirstOrDefault()
               };
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks.  Follow up question, is it possible to do a SelectToken in the Where clause.  i.e. `where (string)issuer["active"] == "1" && security.SelectToken("sedol").Contains("B0XXF09")` ?

Comment: @inquisitive_one - I don't see why not.  Have you tried it?  What was the problem?  Note that `security` must be defined before using it, so you cannot do the check in the `where (string)issuer["active"] == "1"` clause.

Comment: @inquisitive_one - you might not want to use `SelectToken` in the `where` clause if you are going to use the same value later in a `select`.  It will work, but using a separate `let` is more clear.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method that would take a `JToken` and would return an `IEnumerable<JToken>`.  If an array, it'll return the array, otherwise it will return an array of the (assumed) single token.  This will give you a consistent interface, whether there was an array or a single object.

```
public static IEnumerable<JToken> SingleOrMultiple(this JToken source)
{
    IEnumerable<JToken> arr = source as JArray;
    return arr ?? new[] { source };
}
```

Then build you query accordingly.

```
var query =
    from issuer in obj.SelectTokens("DataFeed.Issuer[*]")
    where (int)issuer["active"] == 1
    let security = issuer.SelectToken("securities.Security") as JObject
    where security != null
    let sedol = (string)security["sedol"]
    let customFields = JObject.FromObject(
        security.SelectTokens("customFields.customField[*]")
            .ToDictionary(
                o => (string)o["@name"],
                o => (string)o.SelectToken("values.value")
            )
    )
    let symbolMapping = JObject.FromObject(
        security.SelectToken("symbolMappingList.SecuritySymbol").SingleOrMultiple()
            .ToDictionary(
                o => (string)o.SelectToken("symbolset.name"),
                o => (string)o.SelectToken("symbolset.symbol")
            )
    )
    select new
    {
        CompanyName = (string)issuer["name"],
        Sedol = sedol.StartsWith("0") ? $"'{sedol}" : sedol,
        Adp = customFields["ADP"],
        Isin = symbolMapping["ISIN"],
    };
```

Comment: I get an error:  `Can not convert Array to String.`

Comment: On what? You'll need to provide more details. I get no such error with the sample you provided.