# JSON.Net - Another data retrieval from a polymorphic json string

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, json.net, linq-to-json

Here's what my JSON string looks like:

```
{
    "?xml" : {
        "@version" : "1.0",
        "@encoding" : "UTF-8"
    },
    "DataFeed" : {
        "@FeedName" : "content",
        "now" : "2016-10-17T14:11:38.00",
        "Content" : [{
                "ContentData" : {
                    "@statusType" : "Published",
                    "@isReleased" : "Yes",
                    "@docId" : "21756",
                    "ProductStatus" : {
                        "@productCategory" : "Issuer",
                        "@focus" : "Issuer",
                        "Symbol" : {
                            "@PrimarySymbol" : "GOOGL",
                            "@SecondarySymbol" : "Google",
                            "@BmId" : "1790"
                        }
                    },
                    "ContentVersion" : {
                        "@versionId" : "1",
                        "@lastVersion" : "true",
                        "@lastPublished" : "true",
                        "Url" : [{
                                "@type" : "XML",
                                "@size" : "146410",
                                "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/xml/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.xml"
                            }, {
                                "@type" : "HTML",
                                "@size" : "46105",
                                "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/html/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.html"
                            }, {
                                "@type" : "PDF",
                                "@size" : "1274885",
                                "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/pdf/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.pdf"
                            }, {
                                "@type" : "ALTERNATE PDF",
                                "@size" : "60960",
                                "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/shortPdf/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.pdf"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "ContentData" : {
                    "@statusType" : "Published",
                    "@isReleased" : "Yes",
                    "@docId" : "22457",
                    "ProductStatus" : {
                        "@productCategory" : "Issuer",
                        "@focus" : "Issuer",
                        "Symbol" : {
                            "@PrimarySymbol" : "AAPL",
                            "@SecondarySymbol" : "Apple",
                            "@BmId" : "1121"
                        }
                    },
                    "ContentVersion" : [{
                            "@versionId" : "1",
                            "@lastVersion" : "false",
                            "@lastPublished" : "false",
                            "Url" : [{
                                    "@type" : "XML",
                                    "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/version/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.1476742297.xml"
                                }, {
                                    "@type" : "HTML",
                                    "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/version/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.1476742297.html"
                                }, {
                                    "@type" : "PDF",
                                    "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/version/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.1476742297.pdf"
                                }, {
                                    "@type" : "ALTERNATE PDF",
                                    "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/version/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.1476742297_short.pdf"
                                }
                            ]
                        }, {
                            "@versionId" : "2",
                            "@lastVersion" : "true",
                            "@lastPublished" : "true",
                            "Url" : [{
                                    "@type" : "XML",
                                    "@size" : "174520",
                                    "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/xml/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.xml"
                                }, {
                                    "@type" : "HTML",
                                    "@size" : "46105",
                                    "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/html/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.html"
                                }, {
                                    "@type" : "PDF",
                                    "@size" : "1270150",
                                    "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/pdf/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.pdf"
                                }, {
                                    "@type" : "ALTERNATE PDF",
                                    "@size" : "60960",
                                    "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/version/708893eb-1fd9-4278-8b0e-e7e0738d8105.1577742297_short.pdf"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "ContentData" : {
                    "@statusType" : "Published",
                    "@isReleased" : "Yes",
                    "@docId" : "22501",
                    "ProductStatus" : {
                        "@productCategory" : "Issuer",
                        "@focus" : "Issuer",
                        "Symbol" : [{
                                "@PrimarySymbol" : "AAA",
                                "@SecondarySymbol" : "Some name 1",
                                "@BmId" : "561"
                            }, {
                                "@PrimarySymbol" : "ABC",
                                "@SecondarySymbol" : "Some Name 2",
                                "@BmId" : "29"
                            }, {
                                "@PrimarySymbol" : "BBB",
                                "@SecondarySymbol" : "Some Name 3",
                                "@BmId" : "36"
                            }, {
                                "@PrimarySymbol" : "CCC",
                                "@SecondarySymbol" : "Some Name 4",
                                "@BmId" : "624"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "ContentVersion" : {
                        "@versionId" : "1",
                        "@lastVersion" : "true",
                        "@lastPublished" : "true",
                        "Url" : [{
                                "@type" : "XML",
                                "@size" : "2706269",
                                "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/xml/1c420081-0ce5-4959-91d3-848bbbccd3e3.xml"
                            }, {
                                "@type" : "HTML",
                                "@size" : "32445",
                                "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/html/1c420081-0ce5-4959-91d3-848bbbccd3e3.html"
                            }, {
                                "@type" : "PDF",
                                "@size" : "887608",
                                "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/pdf/1c420081-0ce5-4959-91d3-848bbbccd3e3.pdf"
                            }, {
                                "@type" : "ALTERNATE PDF",
                                "@size" : "34366",
                                "#cdata-section" : "https://aaa.yyy.com/docs/shortPdf/1c420081-0ce5-4959-91d3-848bbbccd3e3.pdf"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm following the code example from [LINQ to Json data retrieval from polymorphic json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793828/linq-to-json-data-retrieval-from-polymorphic-json).  I want to select the following but only if there is a single issuer in `Symbol` section and the PDF url for latest version:

- `@docId`
- `@PrimarySymbol`
- `@BmId`
- `#cdata-section` (but only for PDFs for the latest version)

Here's what my query looks like:

```
from content in jsonFeed.SelectTokens("DataFeed.Content").SelectMany(i => i.ObjectsOrSelf())
let issuer = content
        .SelectToken("ContentData.ProductStatus.@productCategory")
        .SingleOrMultiple()
        .Select(t => (string)t)
        .ToArray()
where issuer.FirstOrDefault().Equals("Issuer")
select new 
{
    DocID = (string)content.SelectToken("ContentData.@docId"),
    Symbol = (string)content.SelectToken("ContentData.ProductStatus.Symbol.@PrimarySymbol"),
    BMId = (int)content.SelectToken("ContentData.ProductStatus.Symbol.@BmId"),
    PDFUrl = (string)content.SelectToken("ContentData.ContentVersion.Url[3].#cdata-section")
}).ToList();
```

Right now, I can successfully get all fields for Google, but I can't get PDFUrl for Apple (because I don't know how to get to the latest version).  Also, how can I complete my Where clause so that it will only select documents with 1 symbol?  So, in the end, my list will be the image below:

[image: Results]

Comment: Do you want the `"@type" : "PDF"` URL, or the `"@type" : "ALTERNATE PDF"` URL?  Because you're currently getting the one at index 3, which is the alternate PDF url.

Comment: Just `"@type": "PDF".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`let`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) and [`where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx) to calculate and filter on intermediate results.

The following query uses this technique, and also queries for the URL with `@type` equal to `"PDF"` rather than hardcoding it to be at index 3 (it's actually at index 2, by the way):

```
string pdfUrlType = "PDF";
var query =
    (from content in jsonFeed.SelectTokens("DataFeed.Content").SelectMany(i => i.ObjectsOrSelf())
     let issuer = content
             .SelectToken("ContentData.ProductStatus.@productCategory")
             .SingleOrMultiple()
             .Select(t => (string)t)
             .ToArray()
     where issuer.FirstOrDefault().Equals("Issuer")
     // Get the @PrimarySymbol where there is exactly one, or null otherwise.
     let symbol = (string)content.SelectToken("ContentData.ProductStatus.Symbol.@PrimarySymbol")
     // Skip content without a single primary symbol
     where symbol != null
     // Get the last ContentVersion record in the JSON document.
     let lastContentVersion = content
        .SelectToken("ContentData.ContentVersion")
        .SingleOrMultiple()
        .Where(v => (bool?)v.SelectToken("@lastVersion") == true)
        .LastOrDefault()
     // Skip content with no ContentVersion
     where lastContentVersion != null
     // Get the PDF Url record
     let pdfUrl = lastContentVersion.SelectToken("Url")
        .SingleOrMultiple()
        .Where(u => (string)u.SelectToken("@type") == pdfUrlType)
        .FirstOrDefault()
     // Skip content with no PDF Url record
     where pdfUrl != null
     select new
     {
         DocID = (string)content.SelectToken("ContentData.@docId"),
         Symbol = symbol,
         BMId = (int?)content.SelectToken("ContentData.ProductStatus.Symbol.@BmId"),
         PDFUrl = (string)pdfUrl.SelectToken("#cdata-section")
     }).ToList();
```

If you actually want the alternate PDF url instead, set

```
string pdfUrlType = "ALTERNATE PDF";
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5QkuDQ).

If you are sure that the the latest version of `ContentVersion` in each `"Content"` record (the one for which `"@lastVersion"` equals `"true"`) is guaranteed to be the last one by document order, you can simplify the query as follows:

```
     let lastContentVersion = content
        .SelectToken("ContentData.ContentVersion")
        .SingleOrMultiple()
        .LastOrDefault()
```